# selecting a actor in a different actor system

Tags: scala, akka, actor

How can a actor select another actor which is of a different actor system?

Consider the below scenario where a there are two actor systems and BikeProducerActor has to be watched by SparePartsProducerAActor. how this can be implemented?

```
object Main extends App{
 val bikeCompanyActorSystem=ActorSystem("BikeCompanyActorSystem")
  val sparePartsCompanyActorSystem=ActorSystem("SparePartsActorSystem")
  val bikeProduceActor=bikeCompanyActorSystem.actorOf(BikeProducerActor.props,"BikeProducer")
  val sparePartsProducerAActor=sparePartsCompanyActorSystem.actorOf(SparePartsProducerAActor.props,"SparePartsProducerA")
  sparePartsProducerAActor ! Common.watchBikeProducer


}
class BikeProducerActor extends Actor{
 def receive={
   case BikeProducerActor.produceBikes => println("Producing bikes")
   case BikeProducerActor.stopProduction => println("Stopping production due to failure in model"); self ! Kill
 }
}

class SparePartsProducerAActor extends Actor{
 def receive={
   case Common.watchBikeProducer => println("watching the bike producer");context.actorSelection("//user/BikeProducer") ! BikeProducerActor.produceBikes
 }
}
```

Comment: Either use the same ActorSystem or Remoting http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/remoting.html

Comment: Is there any way to select the actor in the above scenario without using a remoting?

Comment: I don't believe so, no